# SGE individual job load

Tags: jenkins, sungridengine

I'm dealing with a continuous integration system working on Jenkins with RedHat slaves.

I have sometimes troubles with the queues on some of the slaves (no pattern, alas) which get overloaded.

My main issue is that the slaves are shared and I need to know whether it is my user congesting the queues or someone else. I checked all the options in qstat or qacct but all I can get is the load of the queue as a whole.

With the output of the command below, my question may be clearer:

```
usr100@host210l:/opt/sge/current/util> qstat -f  -l h=host3bx -u \*
    queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. load_avg arch          states
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    all.q@host3bx.site              BIP   0/0/24         2.16     lx24-amd64
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    big.q@host3bx.site              BIP   0/0/4          2.16     lx24-amd64
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    jenkins.q@host3bx.site          BIP   0/7/24         2.16     lx24-amd64
       2285 0.55500 jk7-40192  usr200       r     01/29/2018 05:00:08     1
       2287 0.55500 jk0-40646  usr300       r     01/29/2018 05:00:09     1
       2293 0.55500 jk1-40611  usr100       r     01/29/2018 05:00:10     1
       2299 0.55500 jk5-40112  usr100       r     01/29/2018 05:00:12     1
       2313 0.55500 jk9-40753  usr400       r     01/29/2018 05:00:27     1
       3255 0.55500 jk4-40247  usr500       r     01/29/2018 07:08:09     1
       6743 0.55500 jk4-40545  usr600       r     01/29/2018 12:00:57     1
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    long.q@host3bx.site             BIP   0/0/24         2.16     lx24-amd64
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    short.q@host3bx.site            BIP   0/0/24         2.16     lx24-amd64
```

This is not a problematic example, of course, but it comes in handy.
We see there are 6 users with jobs running in the jenkins queue. I would like to have an idea of which is the individual load of the jobs, out of that 2.16.
Is CPU time (available e.g. with the -ext flag) all I can get or is there something better?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar need,  On our HPC system, admins have full visibility of the load on each computer in the cluster, but ordinary users have no way to see the resource impact of their jobs.  It would be great if there were a tool to run top or htop on a remote node.